# Why is there white border on my :before element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've added a :before pseudo-element, which I've given a box-shadow, to my ul. The reason I've done this is because the header element's drop shadow was hidden behind my drop down menu, and I couldn't manage to resolve the issue with z-index.

So my problem is that while I've given the pseudo-element a height of 1px (in order for box-shadow to display), the element is displaying a thin white line. When I change background color to red for example, it does indeed change from white to red, but setting background color to transparent, or setting hsla with alpha of 0 fails to get rid of a thin white line.
Any suggestions?

[image]

```css
.dropdown-wrapper ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  padding-top: 38px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-wrapper ul:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.15), 0 2px 4px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="content">
  <!-- Navigation Begin -->
  <nav class="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More Info</a></li>
      <li class="no-bot-marg"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="contact-info">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Email address</a></li>
        <li class="no-bot-marg"><a href="#">Phone number</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <img src="#" alt="Logo" class="logo" />
      <nav class="desktop-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
            <p class="noSelect">Services</p>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Automation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="last-link">Data</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="menu-container"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Please edit your example, it does not reproduce what you describe.

Comment: if you need to keep the color of the tiny line and color of the background the same, it should be time to use variables :) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

but its rather guess than solution, because we dont see relevant code